# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Tags: sql, ee-1.14.2.0

On site sometime we face issue with mySql connection timeout

We are using Amazon RDS

Complete error Was

```
a:5:{i:0;s:43:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out";i:1;s:1765:"#0 /documentRoot/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /documentRoot/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /documentRoot/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /documentRoot/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /documentRoot/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /documentRoot/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /documentRoot/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Array)
#7 /documentRoot/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(141): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_setup')
#8 /documentRoot/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup')
#9 /documentRoot/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#10 /documentRoot/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#11 /documentRoot/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /documentRoot/index.php(125): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:100:"/index.php/admin/cache/index/key/516a20d7aac66e35e5c768dce2be889fa303154ebe30b84c046e178f46b01cfd/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I am trying to re-create issue but no luck

can any one tell me where is the issue or how can i re create it

Comment: I too had this issue,  in my case it was giving this error when database cannot handle over load, check the processes which are taking long to complete

Comment: We are using Amazon RDS for mysql and It shouldn't be down.The was facing by client and i am not able to recreate this issue

Comment: Then you should ask your client to guide you on issue, when he/she was facing this issue

Comment: i just check RDS log. There is sometime load on sql server

Comment: you have capacity issues or memory leak

Comment: Currently we are at testing stage. So we try jmeter and create 7+ request per second 200 times but every request was successful.

Comment: @VaibhavAhalpara, how did you fix this?